# Softkeyboard close/hide in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

This question is not for asking any help in the code but rather how to go about keyboard usage in the android application.

I am building a app. My idea is to create a separate class called `HideKeyboard.java` which will contain the code for closing the android softkeyboard, and use this class where ever I use the `EditText Field.`

Is this practice a good one or should I try any other method. Please suggest

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to hide keyboard

```
 private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("in hidemehod");
    if (this.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        System.out.println("hide");
        ((InputMethodManager) EarnedRewardActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus()
                        .getWindowToken(), 0);
        /*
         * inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
         * this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
         * InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
         */
    }
    }
```